# Como poner headers de la consulta de mi api

Tags: java, android-studio, api, get, headers

Estoy tratando de consultar una api en android studio, pero tiene headers, no se en que parte se integran o como.
[image: parametros]
[image: headers]

Agrego el codigo que tenfo en mi apiinterface para poder
realizar la consulta en mi aplicación

```
  
    @GET("https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=MXN&from=USD&amount=1")
    @Headers({"Content-type:text/plain","apikey:NWwDqW5QfiuKQPt9ROyaYm279TaJTlG2"})
    Call<Consul> Consulta(@Query("to") String to,
                          @Query("from") String from,
                          @Query("amount") String amount);
```

y en mi clase para consultar tengo lo siguiente, ya me da los datos en el run pero no me muestra la consulta que le hago porque me manda falla

```
    private void calcular() {
        ApiInterface api = ApiConsultas.getApiService();
        Call<Consul> call = api.Consulta("MXN","USD","1");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Consul>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Consul> call, Response<Consul> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String i = response.body().getResult();
                    System.out.println("Consulte " + i);// NOPMD
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Consul> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hola, agrega el código de como realizas tu petición por favor,  saludos.

Comment: y cuales serial los datos que quieres agregar en el header, porque en Postman los headers se agregan en la pestaña Headers que muestras.

Comment: Y he agregado lo que tengo en mi apiinterface para poder hacer la consulta

Comment: Quiero agregar los headers en Android Studio, pasar la consulta de postman a Android para que sea consultada desde ahí

Comment: Intenta con `@Headers({"Content-type:text/plain","apikey:NWwDqW5QfiuKQPt9ROyaYm279TaJTlG2"})`

Comment: Ya lo agregue, si realiza la consulta ya que se muestra en la consola cuando corre, pero no logra mostrar los datos, añadi mi metodo